# How does JqueryUI read data on your jquery request when downloading data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have date picker and want my date picker to be able get below data that is available, no matter if a user select last year date. eg. 2019-12-04.

On my jquery request I can only get this year date, anyone who can help me to achieve such logic. The logic is below if perhaps I am not making a sense.

HTML:

```
<!---DatePicker for startDate and endDate ---->
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
  <div class="col-xl-10.5 col-lg-10.5 col-md-10 col-sm-10.5 col-10.5">
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Javascript:

```
// date functionality
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    autoclose: true
  });
});

//checking equality for channel fields on thingspeak.
$(function() {
  $("#download").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isTemperature = $('#temperature').is(':checked');
    var isButtonState = $('#button_state').is(':checked');

    if (isTemperature && isButtonState) {
      window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/952961/feeds.csv?api_key=FDJCRN71YJM2R0FM&start=2020-01-06T00:00+02&end=2020-01-10T23:59+02:00&timezone=Africa/Johannesburg');
    } else {
      if (isTemperature) {
        window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/952961/fields/1.csv?api_key=FDJCRN71YJM2R0FM&timezone=Africa/Johannesburg');
      } else {
        if (isButtonState) {
          window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/952961/fields/8.csv?api_key=FDJCRN71YJM2R0FM&start=2020-01-06T00:00+02&end=2020-01-10T23:59+02:00&timezone=Africa/Johannesburg');
        }
      }
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using `input-daterange` in your window.open urls, they're hardcoded to specific date(s).

Comment: Hi Freedom, you right there, how can i use on my logic

Comment: I am trying something like this now, if(isTemperature) {
window.open($('.input-daterange').datepicker({
})
, 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/952961/fields/1.csv?api_key=FDJCRN71YJM2R0FM&timezone=Africa/Johannesburg');
}

Comment: Can any mate help me on this please, i am stuck

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Comment: @Freedomn-m you mentioned something important on top, i am trying some logic around that, kindly please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I made some attempts and finally got it working, but doing this logic below;

```
  // date functionality
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var year = (new Date).getFullYear();
   $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
     format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
     autoclose:true,
     minDate: new Date(year, 0, 1),
     maxDate:new Date(year, 11, 31)

   });
 });
```